# Spark: Aggregation with dynamic filter on a dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like

```
scala> testDf.show()
+------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------+
|    id|    item|    value|  value_name|                               condition|
+------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------+
|    11|    3210|        0|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    12|    3210|        1|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    13|    3210|        0|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    14|    3210|        0|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    15|    3210|        1|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    16|    5440|        5|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    17|    5440|        0|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    18|    5440|        6|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    19|    5440|        7|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    20|    5440|        0|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    21|    7780|        A|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
|    22|    7780|        A|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
|    23|    7780|        A|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
|    24|    7780|        C|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
|    25|    7780|        C|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
+------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------+

scala> testDf.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- condition: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to remove some rows with 'condition' column.
But I am in trouble.

I tried with below test code.
But it does not seem to work properly.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import scala.collection.mutable

val encoder = RowEncoder(testDf.schema);

testDf.flatMap(row => {
  val result = new mutable.MutableList[Row];
  val setting_value = row.getAs[String]("setting_value").toInt
  val condition = row.getAs[String]("condition").toBoolean
  if (condition){
      result+=row;
  };
  result;
})(encoder).show();
```

And This is error.

```
19/05/30 02:04:31 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 267.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 267.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 267.0 (TID 3763, .compute.internal, executor 1): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "setting_value==0"
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.parseBoolean(StringLike.scala:291)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toBoolean(StringLike.scala:261)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toBoolean(StringOps.scala:29)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:40)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I want to keep rows that match the value of the condition column.
This is the desired result.

```
+------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------+
|    id|    item|    value|  value_name|                               condition|
+------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------+
|    11|    3210|        0|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    13|    3210|        0|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    14|    3210|        0|         OFF|                                value==0|
|    16|    5440|        5|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    18|    5440|        6|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    19|    5440|        7|          ON|                     value>0 && value<10|
|    21|    7780|        A|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
|    22|    7780|        A|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
|    23|    7780|        A|        TYPE|   Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|
+------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Please help me if you have a good idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using scala [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054237/what-are-the-ways-to-convert-a-string-into-runnable-code) API withing a UDF function. The udf handles both cases for int and string values:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

val df = Seq(("0","value==0"),
("1", "value==0"),
("6", """value>0 && value<10"""),
("7", """value>0 && value<10"""),
("0", """value>0 && value<10"""),
("A", """Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)"""),
("C", """Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)""")).toDF("value", "condition")

def isAllDigits(x: String) = x.forall(Character.isDigit)

val evalExpressionUDF = udf((value: String, expr: String) => {
  val result =  isAllDigits(value) match {
    case true => tb.eval(tb.parse(expr.replace("value", s"""${value.toInt}""")))
    case false => tb.eval(tb.parse(expr.replace("value", s""""${value}"""")))
  }

  result.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
})

df.withColumn("eval", evalExpressionUDF($"value", $"condition"))
  .where($"eval" === true)
  .show(false)
```

Cases for `evalExpressionUDF`:

- int: replace expression with the actual int value then execute string code with `mkToolBox`
- string: enclose string value into `""` then replace expression with the double quoted string and execute the string code

Output:

```
+-----+-------------------------------------+----+ 
|value|                           condition |eval| 
+-----+-------------------------------------+----+ 
|0    |value==0                             |true| 
|6    |value>0 && value<10                  |true| 
|7    |value>0 && value<10                  |true| 
|A    |Set("A","B").contains(value.toString)|true| 
+-----+-------------------------------------+----+
```

*PS: I know that the performance of the above solution may be bad since it invokes reflection although I am not aware of an alternative.*

Comment: Thank you very much.Your answer is very helpful. But I get an error below. `scala> testDf.withColumn("eval", evalExpressionUDF($"value", $"condition")).show()
` Error : ` org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl, value: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@7341617c) `

Comment: Hi there, what Spark version are you running? and what environment `spark-shell`,`databricks`?

Comment: In spark cluster environment of multi node, it seems that error occurs. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I use spark-shell. and my spark version is 2.4.0.  Scala version is 2.11.12.

Comment: I just ran it in local mode and I get the same error.

Comment: My testDF is processed several times from the source data. If I declare sample dataframe with `val df = Seq` and execute, error does not occur.

Comment: can you try to add this import `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`?

Comment: so if you run the example as I did above it works but in your case your executing more functionality with that dataframe correct?

Comment: Yes. I create testDf by joining some of the source data. There is no use other function than join query using 'spark.sql'.

Comment: I am afraid i can t help without being able to reproduce it although it is certainly related to `val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()`  and the fact that Spark cant serialize the instance of ToolBoxImpl. Please try one more chamge to replace the previous row with `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe 
val cm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val tb = cm.mkToolBox()`

Comment: I used universe.runtimeMirror and I get the same error.
I found another article, do I need to override udf Function1?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848847/define-spark-udf-by-reflection-on-a-string

Comment: yes that seems reasonable. One solution could be move the class loader inside the udf: `val evalExpressionUDF = udf((value: String, expr: String) => {
  val cm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
  val result =  isAllDigits(value) match {
    case true => tb.eval(tb.parse(expr.replace("value", s"""${value.toInt}""")))
    case false => tb.eval(tb.parse(expr.replace("value", s""""${value}"""")))
  }
    result.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
})`

Comment: After move the class loader , I get same error.
But error stack is little different. `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)   ... 51 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror, value: JavaMirror with scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@476c137b of type class scala.tools.nsc.interpreter `

Comment: ok we opened with gates of hell with Spark and reflection together! As you pointed out try to override UDF as shown in the link you sent above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848847/define-spark-udf-by-reflection-on-a-string. I will be on vacation and not able to help any further if the problem remains please consider to post another question. Good luck

Comment: Hello, I have tried to override UDF. But I cant find perfect solution yet. T.T

Comment: If you could send that part of code it would be very helpful n order to be synced

Answer (score 1):

In the above case, Spark is trying to convert the String value to  Boolean. It is not evaluating the expression itself.
And expression evaluation has to be done by the user using an external library or custom code.
The closest(Not the exact scenario though) I could come up is
[How to evaluate a math expression given in string form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) .

Comment: I tried with eval function in scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox. But it is not worked...